# How to use IF / ELSE in a method of Vue

Tags: vue.js

Issue: This method is supposed to accomplish the following:

IF the user is NOT in a specific room already found inside `joinedRooms` then join them and make the room tab above active. (this part works fine as shown below as the if statement)

ELSE (which means the user is already joined to said room), then just take them to the active tab above.

Here is where I am confused. The code below in my eyes SHOULD work. However, it isnt, it seems to always run the IF statement regardless. What is the incorrect syntax being used.

```
    methods: {
        joinRoom(room) {
            if (room != this.$store.state.rooms.joinedRooms) {
            this.$store.dispatch(RoomTypes.JOIN_ROOM, room);
            this.$store.dispatch(RoomTypes.CURRENT_ROOM, room);
            this.$emit('onClose')
            }
            else if (room === this.$store.state.rooms.joinedRooms ) {
                this.$emit('onClose')
            }
        }
    },
```

EDIT: What I am realizing thanks to a comment below is I need to check if the room is part of the array `joinedRooms` How would I accomplish this

Comment: Sure this is just syntax? `joinedRooms` sounds like it's some kind of collection of rooms...

Comment: Have you console logged out the 'room' and 'this.$store.state.rooms.joinedRooms' - what does that return?

Comment: Surely you would agree that an apple isn't equal to the fruit basket it's contained in, wouldn't you? So checking for equality can't be the right approach here. Maybe you are looking for [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)?

Comment: @CherryDT OMG YOU ARE RIGHT... ok let me think about how I would do this now. You are correct. I need to know if the array includes the room not an exact match to the whole array!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @CherryDT, I was able to realize I needed to use includes as part of the if statement. The code should look as follows

```
    methods: {
        joinRoom(room) {
            if (!this.$store.state.rooms.joinedRooms.includes(room)) {
            this.$store.dispatch(RoomTypes.JOIN_ROOM, room);
            this.$store.dispatch(RoomTypes.CURRENT_ROOM, room);
            this.$emit('onClose')
            }
            else if (this.$store.state.rooms.joinedRooms.includes(room)) {
                this.$store.dispatch(RoomTypes.CURRENT_ROOM, room);
                this.$emit('onClose')
            }
        }
    },
```